# How to edit woocommerce sub-category page

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, page-template, sidebar

I am trying to make a product listing site using WooCommerce.

Now the system is when someone clicks on any category, they go to the subcategory page.

I want to add a sidebar with all product categories on the subcategory page. How can I do that?

Here is the link :
https://cctv.abmsrilanka.com/products/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to override the template in WooCommerce which displays the category page and add in your own sidebar / html.

> woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php

You can read up on how to do this here:
https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Don't forget to add theme support in your functions.php file too.

```
function mytheme_add_woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_add_woocommerce_support' );
```